# Is this actually mutating the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just put together a really basic bit of React functionality to show someone and my console tab is accusing me of mutating the state directly.  I thought that as long as you're using `this.setState()` that you're basically fine.

This little bit of code just spits out the first person from the `person` object stored in the state and then when you click the button it increments the age (this actually all works, incidentally).

Am I actually directly mutating the state by doing this?  And if I am, what is the correct way of doing this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
      { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 },
      { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
    ],
  }

  increaseAgeHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: 'Max', age: this.state.persons[0].age += 1 },
        { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 },
        { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>This is an app</h1>
        <button onClick={this.increaseAgeHandler}>Add to age</button>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is a reason your state is out of the constructor?

Comment: @LucasOliveira maybe bcos there is no constructor ?

Answer (score 4):

As `setState` is asynchronous to increase the age by one it is advisable to pass the `prevState` as an argument to the `setState` callback function as below. Also there is no mutation of state if you add `1` to the previous state as below:

```
 increaseAgeHandler = () => {

    this.setState(prevState => {
      persons: [
        { name: 'Max', age: prevState.persons[0].age + 1 },
        { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 },
        { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      ],
    });

  }
```

Comment: AH. Thank you! That totally makes sense, I've heard of `prevState` but never really understood why to use it.  Cheers.

Comment: `prevState` is not a specific keyword of React. It's just an argument passed, not only to `setState`, but also to `componentDidUpdate`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, etc. You may use any identifier instead of 'prevState'

Answer (score 2):

So doing:

```
this.state.persons[0].age += 1
```

Is acutally a mutation you want to create a new pointer for the age variable so you're actually going to do:

```
this.state.persons[0].age + 1
```

This doesn't mutate previous value and adds a new pointer to your state, if you have any questions about this, just shoot! Hope it's understandable.

Comment: That is excellent - now I've seen this it's quite obvious that you can just do `+1` rather than `+=1`.  That tiny change fixes the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state.persons[0].age += 1
```

This changes the `age` directly because `+=` is an **assignment operator**. Instead, just add 1 to the age without assigning:

```
this.state.persons[0].age + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [
       { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
       { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 },
       { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      ]
    };
  }
```

`this.state` it's only assinable on the constructor, then you can update them independently with separate setState() calls.
**Do Not Modify State Directly**

For example, this will not re-render a component:

```
this.state.persons[0].age += 1
```

Instead, use setState():

```
increaseAgeHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: 'Max', age: this.state.persons[0].age += 1 },
        { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 },
        { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
      ],
    });
  }
```

More info about React [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Note that you are still mutating the state directly here because of the assignment operator `+=`.